# PHP Select a Random String from Two Strings

Tags: php, random

```
$apple="";
$banana="";
$apple="Red";
$banana="Blue";

$random(rand($apple, $banana);
echo $random;
```

How can I select a random string (fast) via PHP?

Comment: BTW you dont need to declare variables before use - you can just create `$apple="red";`

Comment: Thanks for that! A bad habit from bad experience - I just do it now for extra safety!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Issue with your code

The PHP `rand()` function takes two numbers as input to form the range to pick a random number from. You cannot feed it strings.

See the [PHP manual page for `rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php).

### Solutions

You can use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand):

```
$strings = array(
    'Red',
    'Blue',
);
$key = array_rand($strings);
echo $strings[$key];
```

---

Another option is to use [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).

```
$strings = array(
    'Red',
    'Blue',
);
shuffle($strings);
echo reset($strings);
```

Comment: Main differences between `shuffle()` and `array_rand()`

Comment: Is that a question? If so their respective code samples above and the relevant linked manual pages clearly show the difference.

Answer (score 40):

What about:

```
$random = rand(0, 1) ? 'Red' : 'Blue';
```

Answer (score 13):

Use an array :

```
$input = array("Red", "Blue", "Green");
echo $input[array_rand($input)];
```

Comment: Repped and this is also an answer to mean - clean simple two line code. Marked the other answer due to explanation and so other may benefit.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid im sorry I dont follow ? "Repped and this is also an answer to mean" ???

Comment: I marked this answer as UP - I "repped" it; I gave it reputation - plus points. And to mean that I am using the code for my solution - the code was not marked as answer fully as the answer above has more explanation that others may benefit - but for your efforts and post I wanted to give some "karma" as they say.

Answer (score 5):

Ran into this old question that tops google's results. You can have more than two options and still get it all on one line.

```
echo ['green', 'blue', 'red'][rand(0,2)];
```

Answer (score 3):

[`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) is probably the best way:

```
$varNames = array('apple','banana');
$var = array_rand($varNames);
echo ${$varNames[$var]};
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `rand()` has two parameters: a lower-limit for a random number and an upper limit. You can not use variables like that because it is not the way the function works.

Take a look at the documentation:
http://php.net/rand

A simple way to achieve what you want is this:

```
$array = array();
$array[0] = 'banana';
$array[1] = 'orange';
$randomSelected = $array[rand(0,(count($array)-1))];
```

As far as I've read, this solution is faster than `array_rand()`. I can see if I can find the source of that.

Comment: Considering this - however everyone on here is saying array_rand()

Comment: I would just use `array_rand()` as this is much harder to read and work out what is going on. Simplicity of maintenance trumps these kinds of micro-optimisations every time.

Comment: True, but most programmers are capable of figuring out this rather simple use of two functions.

Comment: So what exactly is the saving over just using `array_rand()`? CPU proc time is much cheaper than programmers reading odd implementations of standard patterns even if your method is marginally faster.

Comment: For speed. This got it. I am only interested in speed. Thanks

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid It is __not__ faster, but in fact __slower__. See for a performance test between this method and `array_rand()`: http://codepad.org/szIlhXmR

Comment: @OptimusCrime This method is not faster as I have pointed out above. Please consider editing your answer so as not to perpetuate inaccurate micro-optimisations with PHP.

Comment: @Treffynnon : really, I did not know that. Read an article saying my solution was better... hmm, thanks

Comment: Interesting. I may stand to be corrected and will give out an alternative answer award. @OptimusCrime unless you can support your answer. Speed is the most important factor for me.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Always verify peoples micro-optimisations as many of them are inaccurate, outdated or so insignificant that the code smell caused by them is not worth it.